# Spark 0.9.0: worker keeps dying in standalone mode when job fails

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am new to spark.  I am running Spark in standalone mode on my mac.  I bring up the master and the worker and they all come up fine.  The log file of the master looks like:

```
...
14/02/25 18:52:43 INFO Slf4jLogger: Slf4jLogger started
14/02/25 18:52:43 INFO Remoting: Starting remoting
14/02/25 18:52:43 INFO Remoting: Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://sparkMaster@Shirishs-MacBook-Pro.local:7077]
14/02/25 18:52:43 INFO Master: Starting Spark master at spark://Shirishs-MacBook-Pro.local:7077
14/02/25 18:52:43 INFO MasterWebUI: Started Master web UI at http://192.168.1.106:8080
14/02/25 18:52:43 INFO Master: I have been elected leader! New state: ALIVE
14/02/25 18:53:03 INFO Master: Registering worker Shirishs-MacBook-Pro.local:53956 with 4 cores, 15.0 GB RAM
```

The worker log looks like:

```
14/02/25 18:53:02 INFO Slf4jLogger: Slf4jLogger started
14/02/25 18:53:02 INFO Remoting: Starting remoting
14/02/25 18:53:02 INFO Remoting: Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://sparkWorker@192.168.1.106:53956]
14/02/25 18:53:02 INFO Worker: Starting Spark worker 192.168.1.106:53956 with 4 cores, 15.0 GB RAM
14/02/25 18:53:02 INFO Worker: Spark home: /Users/shirish_kumar/Developer/spark-0.9.0-incubating
14/02/25 18:53:02 INFO WorkerWebUI: Started Worker web UI at http://192.168.1.106:8081
14/02/25 18:53:02 INFO Worker: Connecting to master spark://Shirishs-MacBook-Pro.local:7077...
14/02/25 18:53:03 INFO Worker: Successfully registered with master spark://Shirishs-MacBook-Pro.local:7077
```

Now, when I submit a job, the job fails to execute (because class not found error) but the worker also dies.  Here is the master log:

```
14/02/25 18:55:52 INFO Master: Driver submitted org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.DriverWrapper
14/02/25 18:55:52 INFO Master: Launching driver driver-20140225185552-0000 on worker worker-20140225185302-192.168.1.106-53956
14/02/25 18:55:55 INFO Master: Registering worker Shirishs-MacBook-Pro.local:53956 with 4 cores, 15.0 GB RAM
14/02/25 18:55:55 INFO Master: Attempted to re-register worker at same address: akka.tcp://sparkWorker@192.168.1.106:53956
14/02/25 18:55:55 WARN Master: Got heartbeat from unregistered worker worker-20140225185555-192.168.1.106-53956
14/02/25 18:55:57 INFO Master: akka.tcp://driverClient@192.168.1.106:53961 got disassociated, removing it.
14/02/25 18:55:57 INFO Master: akka.tcp://driverClient@192.168.1.106:53961 got disassociated, removing it.
14/02/25 18:55:57 INFO LocalActorRef: Message [akka.remote.transport.ActorTransportAdapter$DisassociateUnderlying] from Actor[akka://sparkMaster/deadLetters] to Actor[akka://sparkMaster/system/transports/akkaprotocolmanager.tcp0/akkaProtocol-tcp%3A%2F%2FsparkMaster%40192.168.1.106%3A53962-2#-21389169] was not delivered. [1] dead letters encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
4/02/25 18:55:57 INFO Master: akka.tcp://driverClient@192.168.1.106:53961 got disassociated, removing it.

14/02/25 18:55:57 ERROR EndpointWriter: AssociationError [akka.tcp://sparkMaster@Shirishs-MacBook-Pro.local:7077] -> [akka.tcp://driverClient@192.168.1.106:53961]: Error [Association failed with [akka.tcp://driverClient@192.168.1.106:53961]] [
akka.remote.EndpointAssociationException: Association failed with [akka.tcp://driverClient@192.168.1.106:53961]
Caused by: akka.remote.transport.netty.NettyTransport$$anonfun$associate$1$$anon$2: Connection refused: /192.168.1.106:53961
] 
...
...
14/02/25 18:55:57 INFO Master: akka.tcp://driverClient@192.168.1.106:53961 got disassociated, removing it.
14/02/25 18:56:03 WARN Master: Got heartbeat from unregistered worker worker-20140225185555-192.168.1.106-53956
14/02/25 18:56:10 WARN Master: Got heartbeat from unregistered worker worker-20140225185555-192.168.1.106-53956
14/02/25 18:56:18 WARN Master: Got heartbeat from unregistered worker worker-20140225185555-192.168.1.106-53956
14/02/25 18:56:25 WARN Master: Got heartbeat from unregistered worker worker-20140225185555-192.168.1.106-53956
14/02/25 18:56:33 WARN Master: Got heartbeat from unregistered worker worker-20140225185555-192.168.1.106-53956
14/02/25 18:56:40 WARN Master: Got heartbeat from unregistered worker worker-20140225185555-192.168.1.106-53956
14/
```

The worker log looks like this

```
14/02/25 18:55:52 INFO Worker: Asked to launch driver driver-20140225185552-0000
2014-02-25 18:55:52.534 java[11415:330b] Unable to load realm info from SCDynamicStore
14/02/25 18:55:52 INFO DriverRunner: Copying user jar file:/Users/shirish_kumar/Developer/spark_app/SimpleApp to /Users/shirish_kumar/Developer/spark-0.9.0-incubating/work/driver-20140225185552-0000/SimpleApp
14/02/25 18:55:53 INFO DriverRunner: Launch Command: "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java" "-cp" ":/Users/shirish_kumar/Developer/spark-0.9.0-incubating/work/driver-20140225185552-0000/SimpleApp:/Users/shirish_kumar/Developer/spark-0.9.0-incubating/conf:/Users/shirish_kumar/Developer/spark-0.9.0-incubating/assembly/target/scala-2.10/spark-assembly-0.9.0-incubating-hadoop1.0.4.jar" "-Xms512M" "-Xmx512M" "org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.DriverWrapper" "akka.tcp://sparkWorker@192.168.1.106:53956/user/Worker" "SimpleApp"
14/02/25 18:55:55 ERROR OneForOneStrategy: FAILED (of class scala.Enumeration$Val)
scala.MatchError: FAILED (of class scala.Enumeration$Val)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(Worker.scala:277)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:498)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:456)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:237)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:219)
        at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:386)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
14/02/25 18:55:55 INFO Worker: Starting Spark worker 192.168.1.106:53956 with 4 cores, 15.0 GB RAM
14/02/25 18:55:55 INFO Worker: Spark home: /Users/shirish_kumar/Developer/spark-0.9.0-incubating
14/02/25 18:55:55 INFO WorkerWebUI: Started Worker web UI at http://192.168.1.106:8081
14/02/25 18:55:55 INFO Worker: Connecting to master spark://Shirishs-MacBook-Pro.local:7077...
14/02/25 18:55:55 INFO Worker: Successfully registered with master spark://Shirishs-MacBook-Pro.local:7077
```

After this in the webUI - the worker is show is dead.

My question is - has anyone encountered this problem. The worker should not die if a job fails.

Comment: I experience the same problem. I found that it also happens after waking the worker machine from the sleep mode.

Comment: Your correct, the workers should not disappear when jobs fail.  I get this too and I have to reboot my worker nodes.

Comment: I created a ticket https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-2019

Answer (score 0):

Check you /Spark/work folder.
You can see the exact error for that particular driver.

For me its a class not found exception.Just give the fully qualified class name for the application main class(include package name too).

Then clear out the work directory and launch your application again in stand alone mode again.
This will work....!

Comment: My problem is not that my application is crashing. But a crash in my application crashes the worker and I have to re-start the worker.

Comment: This issue is resolved in spark 0.9.0 stable release.
https://spark.apache.org/releases/spark-release-0-9-0.html

When running on a Spark standalone cluster with the standalone cluster high availability mode, you can submit a Spark Streaming driver application to the cluster and have it automatically recovered if either the driver or the cluster master crashes.

Comment: Are you sure?  I have been using 0.9.0 version.  Do I need to set configuration change than what is in the default mode?

Comment: I didnt give a try on it.
But still they mentioned it in stable release doc.
spark.apache.org/releases/spark-release-0-9-0.html

Comment: high availability mode has nothing to do with workers, its purpose is to restart master when master node fails. Here the problem is with workers dying when they should not be.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the path to your JAR files.

Pragmatically, you can do it this way:

```
sparkConf.set("spark.jars", "file:/myjar1, file:/myjarN")
```

Which implies you have to first compile a JAR file.

You also have to link dependent JARs - of which there are multiple ways of automating, but well beyond the scope of this question.